# Using FormData with Closest('form')

Tags: jquery

How can I create something like this:

```
var DATA = new FormData($(this).closest('form'));
```

'this' is an input type file. I need to get the form data from the current form that the input is placed inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw HTMLFormElement from the jQuery object by using .get() or getting the array index 0.

Example:

```
var data = new FormData( $(this).closest('form')[0] );
```